# LB_SETITEMDATA ListBox not working Win32 Api c++

Tags: c++, api, winapi, listbox

I've this code that should get the itemID when created and change the code, but it never changes it(At least with my code) and I want to change the item that I select with "LB_ADDSTRING" with "LB_SETITEMDATA". How could I do this? Thanks!

```
//listBox Downloads
        hWndList = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("listbox"), "", LBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 0, ScreenAddaptX(10)+30, ScreenAddaptX(100), ScreenAddaptY(40), hwnd, (HMENU)105, NULL, NULL);
        SendMessage(hWndList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"Downloading Test at 50%");
        int nItem = SendMessage(hWndList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"Downloading Test1 at 70%");
        SendMessage(hWndList, LB_SETITEMDATA, (WPARAM)nItem, (LPARAM)"Downloading Test1 at 90%");
```

Comment: Why are you not checking the return values of function calls?

Comment: There is no `itemID` in your code. You just set item data to a string literal. At least explain what you want to do.

Comment: Explained now @BarmakShemirani

Comment: By the way, `ES_AUTOVSCROLL` is for Edit controls. Don't use for ListBox, because it will be interpreted as some `LBS_XXX` flag whose value happens to coincides with `ES_AUTOVSCROLL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`LB_SETITEMDATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761346(v=vs.85).aspx) sets a user-defined value associated with the specified item in a list box. 
It is not used for changing the item's text.

However, it appears you are trying change the text. For some reason, there is no message for that action, so you have to delete the item and insert a new item with the desired text.

```
int nItem = 1;
SendMessage(list, LB_DELETESTRING, nItem, 0);
SendMessage(list, LB_INSERTSTRING, nItem, (LPARAM)"Downloading Test1 at 90%");
```

Comment: Or, you can owner-draw the ListBox, using `LB_SETITEMDATA` to store the desired text, and  `LB_GETITEMDATA` during drawing to retrieve the text. Then you don't have to delete and reinsert items to change their text. Just `LB_SETITEMDATA` the new text and `InvalidateRect()` to redraw.